# Алгоритм перебора всех сочетаний введенной суммы и размера

Tags: java, алгоритм

Нужен алгоритм. Есть размер size и сумма чисел M, нужно найти все варианты перебора чисел с условием, что сумма в строке M.
Например size = 6, а M = 2.
2 0 0 0 0 0
0 2 0 0 0 0
0 0 2 0 0 0
0 0 0 2 0 0
0 0 0 0 2 0
0 0 0 0 0 2
1 1 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 1 0 0
1 0 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 0 1
0 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 1
0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 1

Comment: А сами-хоть пытались реализовать?

Comment: да, второй день уже, половина минимум теряется где то, если задать M хотя бы 5. А время начинает поджимать сильно.

Comment: Покажите ваш вариант решения, я помогу исправить

Comment: не думаю, что кто-то захочет решать за вас задачу. показывайте свое решение и объясните, что именно не можете реализовать. может что-то и придумаем... на вскидку я бы брал два массива размера size. один хранит комбинации, второй - массив множителей. а потом крутил бы цикл от М до 0. массив множителей, соответсвенно, просчитывает метод, который работает как разряды в калькуляторе, не позволяя при любой комбинации подставить число большее, чем size. а дальше дело техники...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Другими словами, вам надо просто перебрать все способы разложить `M` горошин по `size` стаканам. Ваши комбинации - это просто способы раскладки: количество горошин в каждом стакане.

Пусть положение каждой горошины определяется значением в диапазоне `[0, size)` - это номер ее стакана. Всего горошин `M`. Тогда каждая раскладка горошин однозначно соответствует вектору из `M` чисел. Можно считать этот вектор `M`-значной записью числа в `size`-ричной системе счисления. Однако такая интерпретация раскладок предполагает, что горошины отличаются друг от друга, и раскладки, получающиеся обменом горошин, являются *разными*. (Это ни что иное, как *размещения с повторениями* из `size` по `M`.)

В этой же задаче горошины считаются неотличимыми друг от друга и раскладки, отличающиеся лишь порядком горошин, являются *одинаковыми*. (То есть нас интересуют *сочетания с повторениями* из `size` по `M`.) Чтобы исключить из рассмотрения лишние раскладки, можно ограничиться рассмотрением только `M`-значных чисел в `size`-ричной системе счисления, *у которых цифры в записи не возрастают* (если смотреть от младших к старшим).

Получаем алгоритм: перебираем `M`-значные числа в `size`-ричной системе счисления, у которых цифры в записи не возрастают. И на основе каждого такого числа строим карту раскладки горошин по стаканам.

"Лобовая" реализация этого алгоритма будет может выглядеть так: перебираем все числа от 0 до M<sup>size</sup>-1, проверяем будут ли цифры в `size`-ричной записи этого числа невозрастающими, и если да, то "расшифровываем" раскладку горошин, соответствующую этому числу. Например, на С++

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

unsigned pow(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
  unsigned p = 1;
  for (unsigned n = b; n > 0; --n)
    p *= a;

  return p;
}

bool check_digits(unsigned v, unsigned size)
{
  unsigned prev_digit = -1;
  for (; v > 0; v /= size)
  {
    unsigned digit = v % size;
    if (digit > prev_digit)
      return false;

    prev_digit = digit;  
  }

  return true;
}

std::vector<unsigned> decode(unsigned v, unsigned m, unsigned size)
{
  std::vector<unsigned> r(size);
  for (; m > 0; --m, v /= size)
    ++r[v % size];

  return r;
}

void print(const std::vector<unsigned> &r)
{
  for (unsigned i : r)
    std::cout << i << " ";

  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  const unsigned M = 2;
  const unsigned SIZE = 6;

  for (unsigned v = 0, max = pow(SIZE, M); v < max; ++v)
    if (check_digits(v, SIZE))
      print(decode(v, M, SIZE));
}
```

Результат

```
2 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 1 0 0
1 0 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 0 1
0 2 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 1
0 0 2 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0 1
0 0 0 2 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 2 0
0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 2
```

Но "лобовая" реализация весьма неэффективна именно из-за своей манеры итерировать через все числа, когда нас интересуют далеко не все. Например, для того, чтобы решить задачу для 6 горошин и 6 стаканов эта реализация будет вынуждена сделать 6<sup>6</sup>=46656 итераций, проверяя цифры на каждой из них, в то время как интересующих нас вариантов всего 462. (Не говоря даже об очевидной опасности переполнения при вычислении M<sup>size</sup>.)

Более остроумная реализация не будет перебирать все числа, отсеивая ненужные, а сразу будет генерировать именно и только интересующие нас числа с невозрастающими цифрами. Опять же на С++

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

bool next(std::vector<unsigned> &p, unsigned size)
{
  auto it = p.begin();

  for (; it < p.end(); ++it)
    if (++*it < size)
      break;

  if (it == p.end())
    return false;

  unsigned v = *it;

  while (it != p.begin())
    *--it = v;

  return true;
}

std::vector<unsigned> decode(const std::vector<unsigned> &p, unsigned size)
{
  std::vector<unsigned> r(size);
  for (unsigned i : p)
    ++r[i];

  return r;
}

void print(const std::vector<unsigned> &r)
{
  for (unsigned i : r)
    std::cout << i << " ";

  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  const unsigned M = 2;
  const unsigned SIZE = 6;

  std::vector<unsigned> p(M);
  do
    print(decode(p, SIZE));
  while (next(p, SIZE));
}
```

`M`-значное число в `size`-ричной системе счисления хранится в массиве `p`. Функция `next` дает нам следующее число с невозрастающими цифрами.

---

Ну и напоследок можно заметить, что задача легко решается рекурсивным алгоритмом, который не так интересен, как приведенные выше :)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void print(unsigned m, unsigned size, std::vector<unsigned> &r)
{
  if (size == 1)
  {
    r.push_back(m);

    for (unsigned v : r)
      std::cout << v << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    r.pop_back();
  }
  else
    for (unsigned i = 0; i <= m; ++i)
    {
      r.push_back(i);
      print(m - i, size - 1, r);
      r.pop_back();
    }
}

int main()
{
  const unsigned M = 2;
  const unsigned SIZE = 6;

  std::vector<unsigned> r;
  print(M, SIZE, r);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

вроде работает, может пригодится кому.

```
public static void allCombinations(int m, int n) {
    int[] combination = new int[n + 1];
    Boolean bool = false;
    int t = m;
    int h = 0;
    do {
        if (bool) {
            if (t > 1) {
                h = 0;
            }
            h++;
            t = combination[h];
            combination[h] = 0;
            combination[1] = t - 1;
            combination[h + 1]++;
        } else {
            combination[1] = m;
            for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
                combination[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(combination));
        bool = combination[n] != m;
    } while (bool);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    allCombinations(2, 6);
}
```

Comment: Я тут нашел темку на [mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462099/number-of-possible-combinations-of-x-numbers-that-sum-to-y). В ваш код сидеть и вникать не хочется, скажите только, у вас логически решено подобным образом, или же иначе?

Comment: Если размер задаёшь меньше 6, выдаёт неправильно, лишний нулевой элемент показывает